# MD5 TripleDES Ecryption in Java NoPadding Issue

Tags: java, encryption, tripledes

I need to encrypt data in Java using this **"DESede/CBC/NoPadding"** because in C# it will be decrypted like this:

**C# Code**

```
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            // MD5 the key
            byte[] tdeskey = hashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            // Set Key
            tripDES.Key = tdeskey;
            // Set IV
            tripDES.IV = UTF8.GetBytes(iv);
            // Use CBC for mode
            tripDES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            // Zero Padding
            tripDES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
```

But when I try to do it, I had this kind of error:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length not multiple of 8 bytes
```

So I change it to **DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding**. But now, C# can't read it since **PaddingMode.Zeros** is set on the code above.

Do you have any idea how can I encrypt it sticking on NoPaddingMode?

Comment: Better are PKCS7 padding and AES. But probably the C# code is the reference and can't be changed. The SunJCE provider in Java doesn't support Zero padding. Therefore the padding must be completely disabled with `DESede/CBC/NoPadding` and implemented manually. This is relatively simple: The length of the plaintext must be an integer multiple of the blocksize (8 bytes for 3DES). If this is not the case, `0x00` values must be appended at the end until this condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Beware of defaults.  By encrypting in Java you are implicitly using Java defaults for anything you do not specify.  The C# decryption will use C# defaults, which can be different, causing decryption to fail.  Make sure your specify *everything* explicitly, not allowing any defaults.  The smallest mismatch will cause decryption to fail.

Comment: Also note that C# seems to automatically use [2TDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) for a 16 bytes key (like here due to MD5), while in Java (at least for the SunJCE provider) a 24 bytes key is expected (i.e. the key must be manually extended to match 2TDEA).